# scala: how to define an object with explicit class type

Tags: class, scala, object

I understand the difference between object and class. Object is a singleton with anonymous class type. But in my play framework within xxx.scala.html file, it doesn't recorgnize the object name as type name. It report error that no type found.  For instance: 
Object ABC extends Enumeration{
....
}

In xxx.scala.html, define a variable abc:ABC, it will report no type found error, while other class type can be easily defined in this file.

How can I define an object with explicit class name, so that I can use it?

Answer (score 1):

You could always use `ObjectName.type`. For instance:

```
trait Test
object A extends Test

def test(a: A.type) = a

test(A) // compiles fine
test(new Test{}) // compilation error
```

Note that in case of `object ABC extends Enumeration{...}` you should use `ABC.Value` as type of instances:

```
object ABC extends Enumeration{ val A, B, C = Value}

def test(a: ABC.Value) = a

scala> test(ABC.A)
res0: ABC.Value = A
```

Comment: @user2512057: you could accept an answer if it works for you.